# Query string writing method when sending a request to the API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, request, query-string

In my .net core project I want to throw a request full of parameters to my get method in the API. Since I have too many parameters when making a request, I do not want to do it with the method I specified below. Is there a way you can suggest? In addition, can't I write my parameters one by one in the URL without using my helper method called `BuildQueryString`?

```
UI Controller
var departmentsDto = await _apiServiceManager.OrganisationItemApiServices.GetDataPaged(PageIndex,SearchText, ActiveStatus, ItemType, UpdatedDate, OrderBy,25);
```

The `ApiService` I'm requesting to the `API` on the `UI` side

```
public async Task<JObject> GetDataPaged(int PageIndex, string SearchText, int ActiveStatus, int ItemType, DateTime? UpdatedDate, string OrderBy, int Take)
        {
            var url = BuildQueryString($"api/OrganisationItem/GetDataPaged", PageIndex, Take, SearchText, ActiveStatus, ItemType, UpdatedDate, OrderBy);
}
    ...
    private string BuildQueryString(string baseUrl, int pageIndex, int take, string searchText, int activeStatus, int itemType, DateTime? updatedDate, string orderBy)
            {
                var queryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(baseUrl);
                queryStringBuilder.Append($"?PageIndex={pageIndex}");
                queryStringBuilder.Append($"&Take={take}");
                queryStringBuilder.Append($"&SearchText={searchText}");
                queryStringBuilder.Append($"&ActiveStatus={activeStatus}");
                queryStringBuilder.Append($"&ItemType={itemType}");
    
                if (updatedDate.HasValue)
                {
                    queryStringBuilder.Append($"&UpdatedDate={updatedDate}");
                }
                queryStringBuilder.Append($"&OrderBy={orderBy}");
    
                return queryStringBuilder.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Of course you can add parameters one by one in the URL in `GetDataPaged` method, But i am confused why you don't wanna use `BuildQueryString` method?

Comment: I have pages where I need to get a lot of parameters, so I'm looking for an alternative way.

Comment: You think use `queryStringBuilder.Append(xxx)` to add parameter in `BuildQueryString` method one by one is too Inefficient? In my opinion, You can receive a model in `BuildQueryString` method, Then iterate over all properties and related values in that model and add them in url, I am not sure if you wan this way.

Comment: how can I do that? can you write sample code?

Comment: Hi @nikki, I create a simple demo to show my opinion, Hope it can help you solve this issue.

Comment: Hi @nikki, If this answer can help you solve this issue, could you mark it as the answer? Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure, i would gladly do that @XinranShen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, You can receive `Dictionary<string,object>` in `BuildQueryString` method, Then in different endpoint, you can pass different data to this method to generate url, Please refer to this simple demo:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Add(int id,string name,int age,DateTime? dateTime)
        {
            var baseUrl = "api/OrganisationItem/GetDataPaged";
            var param = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                 { "id", id },
                 { "name", name },
                 { "age", age }
            };
               

            if (dateTime.HasValue)
            {
                param.Add("dateTime",dateTime);
            }
            var result = BuildQueryString(baseUrl,  param);

            

            return Ok(result);
        }


        private string BuildQueryString(string baseUrl, Dictionary<string, object> obj)
        {
        
            var urlBuilder = new UriBuilder()
            {
                Scheme = "http",
                Host = "localhost",
                Path = baseUrl
            };

            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(urlBuilder.Query);


            foreach (var kvp in obj)
            {
                query[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value.ToString();
            }

            urlBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
            var url = urlBuilder.ToString();

            return url;
        }
```

[image]